# How to redirect user to an error page from login control upon entering wrong username and/or password?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I created a login form, and when I log in using a correct username and password it works fine.
I want to pop up an error message or error page when I enter a wrong username or password.
That means the controller will compare the given username with all the usernames in the database and if the given username is not found, an error message or error page should be displayed.

How can I do this with HTML or JavaScript?  Is there a way to create a simple error message in the servlet? but I need to reload the page again.

```xml
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="search" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <table>
        <tr><td>Username</td>
            <td><input type=text name=LoginId /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Password</td>
        <td><input type=password name=LoginPassword /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan=2>
              <center>
                <input type=submit value=SignIn /><br>If you forgot your password, <a href="ResetPassword"> Reset </a>your password.
              </center>
           </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

## SearchServlet.java

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public SearchServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CustomerDAO customerDAO = new CustomerDAO();
    String username = request.getParameter("LoginId");
    String password = request.getParameter("LoginPassword");
    Login login = customerDAO.getLoginByName(username, password);


    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("<center><h1>User Information</h1></center>");
    out.println("<center><table border=0x>");
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td>Login Id : </td><td>"+login.getLoginId()+"</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td>City : </td><td>"+login.getCity()+"</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td>State : </td><td>"+login.getState()+"</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td>Cell Number : </td><td>"+login.getCellnumber()+"</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td>Email :</td><td>"+login.getEmail()+"</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td>Address :</td><td>"+login.getAddress()+"</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td>ZipCode : </td><td>"+login.getZipcode()+"</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
    out.println("</table></center>");
    out.println("<p>If these details are correct press continue or to change your information press update.</p>");
    out.println("<form action='Continue.jsp'>");
    out.println("<center><input type=submit value=continue></center>");
    out.println("</form>");
    out.println("<form action='search'>");
    out.println("<center><a href=Update?City="+login.getCity()+"&State="+login.getState()+"&PhoneNumber="+login.getCellnumber()+"&Email="+login.getEmail()+"&Address="+login.getAddress()+"&ZipCode="+login.getZipcode()+"> update </a></center>");          
    out.println("</form>");
    out.println("</body></html>");


    Login l = new Login();
    l.setLoginId(request.getParameter("LoginId"));

    if(l!=null) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("l", l);
        }

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}

}
```

## CustomerDAO.java

```
public class CustomerDAO extends BaseDAO{


public Login getLoginByName(String username, String password) {
    Login login = null;
    try {
        BaseDAO baseDAO = new BaseDAO();
        Connection c =baseDAO.getConnection();
//      String query = "select * from test.Login where LoginId=? && LoginPassword=?";
        String query = "select * from test.Customer where LoginId=? && LoginPassword=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            login = new Login();
            login.setLoginId(rs.getString("LoginId"));
            login.setCity(rs.getString("City"));
            login.setState(rs.getString("State"));
            login.setCellnumber(rs.getString("PhoneNumber"));
            login.setEmail(rs.getString("Email"));
            login.setAddress(rs.getString("Address"));
            login.setZipcode(rs.getInt("ZipCode"));
            System.out.println();
        }
        c.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Username or Password you enterd is incorrect.");
    }
    return login;
}
```

## Login.java

```
package com.dao;

public class Login {

String LoginId;
String password;
String confirmpassword;
String city;
String state;
String cellnumber;
int zipcode;
String Email;
String Address;

public Login() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getLoginId() {
    return LoginId;
}

public void setLoginId(String loginId) {
    LoginId = loginId;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getConfirmpassword() {
    return confirmpassword;
}

public void setConfirmpassword(String confirmpassword) {
    this.confirmpassword = confirmpassword;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getCellnumber() {
    return cellnumber;
}

public void setCellnumber(String cellnumber) {
    this.cellnumber = cellnumber;
}

public int getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}

public void setZipcode(int zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    Address = address;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}
}
```

Comment: What is `Login` can you explain ?

Comment: You might want to just consider using container-based security, unless that's not an option.  You can configure a login page and a login error page, among other benefits of the approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after this :

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

add ->

```
if (login == null){
   out.println("<html><body>");
   out.println("<center><h1>Login failed, wrong username or password</h1></center>");
   out.println("</body>");
   out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>");
   out.println("function reload() {");
   out.println("setTimeout(function(){");
   out.println("window.location = '"+request.getContextPath()+"/search';}");
   out.println("}, 5000);");
   out.println("reload();");
   out.println("</script>");
   out.println("</html>");
}
```

}

but that is a bad way to do authentication, you will have to write your own authorization filters, and thats a lot of redudant code, instead of this use web containers authentication mechanism see [securing web app](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncby/index.html)

it's easy to override, can add custom login, add softlogin, roles, and stuff like this.

Comment: It is working but i need to reload the page again along with this message. How is it possible?

Comment: i quess your need to reload the page after showing the message, i updated the answer, so the after the error is shown, the browser will redirect to /search servlet after 5 seconds